# Identify when jQuery load() has finished loading multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a script that uses jQuery's `getScript()` function to dynamically load blog posts from tumblr accounts.

The script response is a JSON structure `tumblr_api_read` that contains (amongst other things) image urls.

```
function read(blogName) {
    var imageUrls = [];
    $.getScript("http://" + blogName + ".tumblr.com/api/read/js", function() {
        imageUrls = getImageUrls(tumblr_api_read.posts); // returns an array of URLs to use as img src attributes
    }).done(function(script, textStatus) {
        loadImages(imageUrls);
        processTumblrResponse(); // ### ONLY EXECUTE WHEN IMAGES ARE LOADED!!
    });
}
```

I use the imageUrls array in my function loadImages() to inject `<img/>`s into the DOM via jquery-built var `$temporaryImageContainer` and then carry out some further processing.

```
var imgAjaxComplete = false;
var imgCount = 0;

function loadImages(imageUrls, $temporaryImageContainer) {
    while (!imgAjaxComplete) {
        for (srcKey in imageUrls) {
            var $image = $("<img>", {"id" : "imageUrl" + srcKey, "src" : imageUrls[srcKey]})
                .load(function() {
                    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                        console.log("Error loading image: " + imageUrls[srcKey]);
                    } else {
                        $temporaryImageContainer.append($image);
                        console.log("Loaded image: " + imageUrls[srcKey]);
                    }
                });
            ++imgCount;
        }
        if (imgCount == imageUrls.length) {
            imgAjaxComplete = true;
            imgCount = 0;
        }
    }
    console.log("loadImages() complete");
}

function processTumblrResponse() {
    console.log("Images loaded. Running processTumblrResponse()");
    // further processing here...
}
```

The trouble with this is that the `for` loop in `loadImages()` executes before anything else (I think that's what's happening anyway) and it only ever tries to load the last image src in `imageUrls` n times (where n is `imageUrls.length`).

Is it possible to identify when all of the images injected into the DOM have finished loading BEFORE I carry out the additional processing?

The JSON is too large to post here but let me know if it's needed for context.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your function `loadImages` with this here :

```
function loadImages(imageUrls, $temporaryImageContainer) {
        for (srcKey in imageUrls) {
            var $image = $("<img>", {"id" : "imageUrl" + srcKey, "src" : imageUrls[srcKey]})
                .load(function() {
                    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                        console.log("Error loading image: " + imageUrls[srcKey]);
                    } else {
                        $temporaryImageContainer.append($image);
                        console.log("Loaded image: " + imageUrls[srcKey]);
                    }
                    imgCount++;
                    checkIfImagesAreLoaded();
                });
        }
}
function checkIfImagesAreLoaded() {
    if (imgCount === imageUrls.length) {
        imgCount = 0;
        imgAjaxComplete = true;
        console.log("loadImages() complete");
    }
}
```

As for the explanation, the for loop completes before anything else because the jQuery `load` function executes the method you pass in as a parameter only when the image is loaded, so it doesn't get called right away.

**EDIT:**
You should not use `for (x in array)` in Javascript, as this loop is for iterating properties of an object. Unfortunately the best practice is to use `for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) ...`.

See W3Schools for loop documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

You could also use :

```
yourArray.forEach(function(item) {
    //Do crazy stuff here
});
```

But `forEach()` is part of ES5 and it won't be supported in older browsers like IE8 and below.

Comment: +1 for the loop info but I'm not clear on when to call checkIfImagesAreLoaded()?  Tried it with a setTimeout but I still see the same behaviour.

Comment: Sorry you should use `checkIfImagesAreLoaded()` at the end of your callback passed in the `load` function. See the edit I just made.